SSH connection drops when executing long-running command, but not when idle
I connect to some production Ubuntu systems through a bastion host using SSH-tunnelling. Recently, I have found that when executing long running commands on the production systems (eg. backup and restore tasks or archiving jobs), my SSH connections drop after a few minutes. On the other hand, if I just leave the terminal sessions to bastion and production host idle, these will happily remain connected for much longer.
Looking at the terminal output on the host where I run a long duration task, it appears never to have completed the task in question, though so far, I have thankfully not noted any cases where it actually did not complete (this is without me using any special measures such as nohup).
I don't know exactly at what point the disconnection occurs as I have not sat long enough to watch it. When the connection does drop, it is both from the production host and the bastion host, so presumably the latter is causing it.
I am not certain what change caused this behaviour to start occurring. Any pointers on how/where to diagnose and resolve this one?

You could monitor the connection with wireshark but that won't necessarily identify where the issue as arising unless you are tapping the connection in multiple locations.
I'd suggest using ssh's ServerAliveInterval to keep the connection active (and in the state tables of intervening devices) before trying to diagnose further. How you do that depends on which client you are using. If its openssh, this can be set on the command line or in the ssh_config. See the man page for sepcifics.

When (at which point) it breaks you can infer from the server logs. The ssh should drop a line that certain client was disconnected. Other than that, start monitoring the network, there is only one way. Traffic capture might help, too, but most often it's too heavy for this task. What if it's a matter of hours, do you expect to store hours of traffic capture?
I have one explanation how this could happen. It all based on the fact that when you have an idle SSH session it really sends absolutely nothing.
I had, for instance, rebooted a DSL modem through which the connection was established; after the modem coming back up it continued to work as if nothing happened, because no TCP RSTs or missing ACKs or whatever was encountered by either side for that connection. But, that only worked if I didn't touch the session while modem isn't ready. If, however, I tried to do anything with the connection while modem is rebooting, it was bound to break due to TCP timeout.
So, if the physical connection that you are using has intermittent issues it may be not noticeable if idle connections aren't happen to be used when issues arise, but if your long-running tasks output something constantly (and even special characters that don't advance screen output are still being sent over the network), that makes the SSH connections break during issues.
The suggestion by @symcbean in another answer to adjust ServerAliveInterval can be a two-headed sword. It changes this behaviour, in that idle client starts to send a periodic "pings" to the server, so it's not that idle anymore, and it starts noticing even brief issues. It may so happen that even "idle" connections that didn't break before start breaking.
Also note that ServerAliveInterval is one-sided. It only makes client to do monitoring of the connection. It may happen that client notices the disconnection due to this setting, but the server doesn't because it doesn't care. There is a corresponding setting for the server, ClientAliveInterval, which is set in sshd_config and makes server to monitor client availability the same way. If you want both sides to be aware, use both features.

Worth noting that "special measures like nohup" are not special at all, they're good practice. It's advisable to run all long-running commands within screen or tmux session which are modern fancy replacements for the nohup. Notable example is a Debian system upgrade manual which recommends to work in a screen session if you're ever going to perform the upgrade remotely.
The only case when it wouldn't help you is the long-running task itself tunnels something through the connection that breaks.
